# Why can't I access a catalyst model's config from inside the model itself?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a class that looks like this:

```
package MyApp::Model::Skunk::Find::Images;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

extends 'Catalyst::Model::Factory';

use Data::Dump qw/dump/;

sub prepare_arguments {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    # these are for debugging purposes only

    $c->log->info("package: " . __PACKAGE__);
    $c->log->info("catalyst config: " . dump $c->config);
    $c->log->info("images class: " . __PACKAGE__->config->{class});
    $c->log->info("images root: " .  __PACKAGE__->config->{root});

    return { root => __PACKAGE__->config->{root} };
}
```

and myapp.conf looks like this (snippet):

```
<Model::Skunk::Find::Images>
    root    '/foo/bar/myapp/data/img'
    class   MyApp::Find
</Model::Skunk::Find::Images>
```

I can access the whole application config hash (I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776087/access-config-from-inside-catalyst-model) answer), but I cannot seem to be able to access the class' config directly, so

```
 $c->log->info("images class: " . __PACKAGE__->config->{class});
 $c->log->info("images root: " .  __PACKAGE__->config->{root});
```

from within MyApp::Skunk::Find::Images both produce nothing.

If I configure the variables from inside the package like this:

```
__PACKAGE__->config( 
                    class => 'MyApp::Find',
                    root  => '/foo/bar/myapp/data/img'
                   );
```

everything works fine.

Can anyone help explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config for a Catalyst component is passed to its constructor. You should just do in your Model:

```
has ['class','root'] => (
   isa => 'Str',
   is => 'ro',
);
```

and in your methods use `$self->class` and `$self->root`. Accessing `__PACKAGE__->config` within a component (except once, during startup, to *set* config) is a mistake. Looking in `$c->config` is even further off the mark.

Comment: Excellent, the correct answer.  I would also add that if a model needs access to the Catalyst object, then the design is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. My goal is to be able to set some parameters from myapp.conf at startup, same as one can set the dbi connection there - see the example in the docs for Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema